# Appending a string from source to destination with the use of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm trying to rewrite a string append function with the use of pointers. My string append function, which doesn't explicitly use pointers, looks something like this:

```
void append_a_string(char a[], b[]) {
    int i, j;
    j = length of string a;
    while (b[i]) {
        a[i] = b[i]
            i++;
        j++;
    }
    b[j] = 0;
}
```

Where I take the length of string "a" with a pre-made function. I'm confused exactly how to use pointers in this situation. This is what I have so far:

```
void append_a_string(char *a, char *b) {
    a = length of string a;
    while (b) {
        b = a;
        a++;
        b++;
    }
    b = 0;
}
```

Comment: They both use pointers. `char a[]` is just another way of saying `char *a` (but IANALL).

Comment: Yes I understand. However, I'm trying to write the code so that I explicitly use pointers as opposed to implicitly using them via character arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should be:

```
void append_a_string(char *a, char *b) {
    a += length of string a;
    while (*b) {
        *a = *b;
        a++;
        b++;
        }
    *a = 0;
}
```

You can use the functions in string.h:

```
#include<string.h>
strcpy(a+length_of_string_a, b); //if you know the length of a
strcat(a, b); //if you don't know the length of a
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Why do you add the length of the string in a, as opposed to assigning it? Secondly, why is there no equivalent statement to b[j] = 0?

Comment: You want to append `b` to `a`. `a+length_of_string_a` is the end of `a`. Copying `b` to the end of `a` is append `b` to `a`. You should set the last byte of `a` to 0, not the last byte of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the refined code:

```
void append_a_string(char *a, char *b) {
    a += strlen(a);
    while (*b) {
        *a++ = *b++;
    }
    *a = '\0';
}
```

It is `a` that requires a null-terminal, rather than `b`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I get it now!!

Comment: @zzzOp You may consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer if you feel it solves your problem :)

Comment: do you mean while (*b) instead? , may be while (*a++ = *b++) ;

Comment: @bare_metal Oh yes, thanks for pointing that out. And I think `while (*a++ = *b++) ;` seems a little confusing.